# A flexible enumeration for my maths dissertation

Tags: numbering, theorems

So I'm currently writing my maths dissertation.

Say I am in "section 5" of the dissertation and am ordering lemmas, propositions, theorems and corollaries by 5.1, 5.2, 5.3,... etc. Is there a way to code this enumeration so that if I wanted to add a new 5.2, the old 5.2 would change to 5.3, 5.3 would change to 5.4,... etc?

Thanks for any help

Comment: This is the default behavior of LaTeX system. Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. I think there is a misunderstanding here.

Comment: What you describe is how all latex numbering works. So if it isn't working you need to show us what you did.

Comment: As the previous comments say this is LaTeX default _provided_ one uses LaTeX's `\newtheorem` etc. to set up these environments, e.g. `\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]` etc. You should then place `\label` and reference them with `\ref` to refer to these environments. See LaTeX documentation, and possibly consider either `amsthm` or `ntheorem` packages for more sophisticated formatting.

Comment: Thanks guys. I'm completely new to this all. I'll check out \newtheorem{thm} et al.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hopefully you've discovered that the problem is easy in LaTeX (indeed, it is substantially what it was *designed* for), but here is an explicit construction for you to look at.

Try compiling this document, both with and without the Lemma in it. (Depending on how you are writing your document, you may have to run LaTeX twice in a row to make the cross-reference resolve each time you remove the Lemma. Many modern editors do this automatically.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb}    
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
% Theorem numbering is Sec#.Thm#
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
% Lemmata are numbered as theorems

\begin{document}
\section{A section with some politically motivated math in it}

The following Lemma is folklore among Business Administration circles of
the \emph{Paradigmatic Shift} school:

\begin{lemma}[Synergy Lemma]
    \label{lemma:synergy}
    Under the right circumstances, $1 + 1 = 3$.
\end{lemma}
\begin{proof} By adoption of a positive workplace culture. \end{proof}
\noindent
The Synergy Lemma proves quite useful to show the following celbrated result:

\begin{theorem}
    \label{thm:2+2=5}
    When it suits us, $2 + 2 = 5$. 
\end{theorem}
\begin{proof} Exercise for the reader; use good stomping boots. \end{proof}
\noindent
Theorem~\ref{thm:2+2=5} is commonly known as \emph{Orwell's Theorem},
though it is often (and more accurately) called \emph{Vissarionovich's Theorem}
in many eastern European countries.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. As I am just starting with latex I really find illustrated examples helpful.